# Qt can't access some .dll files

Tags: qt, dll

I am working on a plugin for some application, and I am using libtiff. The filter is working just fine, but there is a problem. There are some .dll files that have to be included in compile path. When I add those .dlls in \QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\bin the plugin is working fine, but when i delete one or more of those .dlls, plugin is not recognised by the application. Those .dll are not included in the Qt SDK by default.

Is there any way I can include those .dll in my plugin and add a path to them without copying them to the Qt SDK bin folder.

Comment: In a folder where plugin header and source files are

Comment: Not where, what. The names :-). Your MinGW/bin is in your search path. No wonder that they are found there. You should be able to put them in the same folder in which your program is started.

Comment: My fault :). 
They should be located in the same folder as plugin's source file is. Is there a posibility to reach them without copying them in mingw/bin?

Comment: The location of the source files is irrelevant. Try putting them in the same folder where the binary lies.

Comment: I did that and same thing is happening.

Comment: Then I am out of options. Things like that are extremely hard to debug 'remotely'. Position dependent dlls are strange. Only other example of something like that, which I know, are the Qt plugins.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but QT is not Qt. QT refers to Apple QuickTime and not the Nokia Qt framework. I edited the question to replace all QT with Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I add my plugins to my application directory and add this line of code to `main()` in main.cpp like so:

```
qApp->addLibraryPath(QString("."));
```

Image plugins go in `imageformats` and SQL drivers (ODBC) go in `sqldrivers`. You can make the library path anything you want relative to your application root directory. I like to keep things simple and just reference the root directory.